# AddSingleton<TService, TImplementation>() Vs AddSingleton<TService>() and AddSingleton<TImplementation>(s => s.GetService<TService>())

Tags: c#

When using DI in C#, I would normally add a singleton service that I want to inject somewhere in the following way

```
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<MyService>();
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IMyService>(s => s.GetRequiredService<MyService>());
```

It has recently been pointed out to me that I can actually use

```
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IMyService, MyService>();
```

and achieve the same result.

Going forward I think I am going to use the latter method but I want to know if there is any difference between the two at all?

I feel like my first example is much more explanitory to someone trying to learn the language, you can see I'm adding my implementation and then going on to say when I request a service using my interface give me this implmentation here, but the latter is much cleaner for people already familliar the language and services. I think this is the main difference.

Are there any technical differences, or is it just semantical?

Comment: You have the second way backwards. `IMyService` needs to be the first type parameter, `TService`, and `MyService` is the second, `TImplementation`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, will edit the Q

Comment: You fixed the code in the body but the title was correct in the first place. Revert that part of the change.

Comment: The second way is better.  `I feel like my first example is much more explanitory to someone trying to learn the language` I'm not coding in a production environment with a mind to teach people.  Anyone who knows about DI in .NET knows the syntax for `AddSingleton<TInterface, T>`.  Not that training is not important, but they should learn the normal syntax

Comment: The first way registers both types, so by `IMyService` and `MyService` are both injectable. The second makes the concrete type not injectable, which is the purpose of using (and injecting by) an interface in the first place: don't allow binding to the concrete type.

Comment: @Jonesopolis, seems a fair point

Comment: @madreflection both IMyService and MyService being injectable didnt even cross my mind but obviously makes sense now. I guess the latter method should be prefered then in cases like this?